# Django media URLs in CSS files

Tags: django, django-templates

In django templates, it's common to do the following:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/img/someImage.jpg">
```

How would you accomplish this in a CSS file which is not served as a template?

```
.someClass {
    /* can't do this this */
    background: url("{{ MEDIA_URL }}/img/someImage.jpg");        
    /* either this */
    background: url("http://media.domain.com/img/someImage.jpg");
    /* or this */
    background: url("/django_static_media/img/someImage.jpg");
    /* can't do both... what to do? */
}
```

I need the ability to serve my files either from the media subdomain, or during offline work and serve them directly as a django static view. But CSS files are a problem since they are not processed as templates and I cannot use the `MEDIA_URL` context variable.

What's the solution?

**Edit:** I should note that the problem arises since my static media files are in fact located on a separate media sub-domain, <strike>thus negating the use of relative paths.</strike> Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Where is your css file served from? This usually isn't a problem as a common media structure such as:

```
media/
    images/
    css/
    js/
```

(or similar) allows for relative file paths for images, eg:

```
background: url('../images/foo.png');
```

If you're not prepared to change your media folder structure to accommodate relative file paths, you may have no alternative but to overwrite css declarations from within the template, using a secondary css file when offline:

```
{% if DEBUG %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/offline-mode.css" />
{% endif %}
```

Of course the first option is much tidier.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, you won't like the answer.

I've got the same problem:

There is no easy way to do this with static-served CSS files.

What I do:

- debug server, work locally, media served locally
- production server is hosted out somewhere commercial w/media on Amazon S3
- settings.py file auto sets MEDIA_URL (DEBUG, etc.) via hostname check (to differentiate production vs. local/home/debug)
- HTML files all have css links with
  {{MEDIA_URL}} (+RequestContext
  contexts for views)
- I like absolute path names, so an "update_s3" script: 
  **(1)** alters each css file is temporarily to fix 
  'url("/media' to 'url("s3.mydomain.com/media' and 
  **(2)** updates/uploads my /media directory to Amazon S3

I then go to production and do an svn update & touch the WSGI file & validate

Answer (score 3):

Is using relative paths (for image files) in your CSS files not a viable option for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use template directives in a file, why isn't it served via a template?